# podman container prune: Error: container not known

Tags: container, podman

When I run `podman container prune`, I get

```
$ podman container prune
WARNING! This will remove all non running containers.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Error: container not known
```

Same thing if I try to force it with `-f`

```
$ podman container prune -f
Error: container not known
```

What is causing this error and how can I resolve it?

Comment: please file a bug, it's happening in rootless running podman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was able to do is rather than prune them, just remove them.

```
podman container rm -a
```